# Task gets stuck on Airflow when the DB is unreachable

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-2.x

Too many tasks running at the same time on Airflow, some tasks get heartbeat exception and they get stuck. Sometimes even if the tasks are completed, the airflow can't get the completed log.

our setup:
Airflow v2.3.4 in Docker
PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

example log:

```
[2022-10-19, 09:01:15 +03] {base_job.py:229} ERROR - LocalTaskJob heartbeat got an exception
....
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "xxx" (xxx), port xxx failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
....
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "xxx" (xxx), port xxx failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```